# can't connect mysql workbench with XAMPP mysql

Tags: mysql, windows, ssl, xampp, mysql-workbench

I have MySQL workbench 8.0 CE.
XAMPP MySQL running on port 3306 and I can't connect MySQL on the workbench
[image]

Even then I tried to change the SSL tab but there are not enough options
[image]

So how can I connect it?

Comment: I think the problem is related to how you set up authentication for your MySQL database. Are you using the MySQL provided by XAMPP or have you separately installed MySQL? If you have separately installed MySQL and you will only be using this database to learn development, you should reinstall it using the 'Legacy Authentication'.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench 8.0.29 restores the SSL options in the SSL tab.
You can now select "If available" in the Use SSL dropdown box of the SSL tab of the connection pane again. 
Use the tool icon in the startup window to edit already existing connections.